# Retofit2: posting a list of maps as List<Map> into @Field, not @Body

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

Here is my service:

```
public interface ISensorService {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("sensor/bvp")
    Call<BvpResponse> sendBvp(
            @Field("device") String device,
            @Field("cluster[]") List<Map<String, Float>> cluster
    );
}
```

A cluster is an ArrayList of HashMap.

The server receives the request but the cluster prop is an array with stringified values:

```
[
"{ts=22.0, bvp=3.8199387}",
"{ts=22.0, bvp=3.8199387}",
"{ts=22.0, bvp=3.8199387}",
]
```

How to send this prop as a JSON array?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: try to send it as body

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: ok i got it. It works, thanks :)